# Index of For Loop as Parameter in Pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have the same issue as with this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096161/how-can-i-pass-the-index-of-a-for-loop-as-the-argument-for-pthread-create). However, I am using C, not C++ and can't follow the accepted solution. I have tried using the second solution but that does not work either. Is there any way that I can pass the value of the loop variable and not the variable itself in C?

Comment: The accepted solution works fine in C.

Comment: @Fredrik new int(i) causes it to not compile

Comment: Ofc not that is C++. allocate a new int for each thread and pass it to the function. That was the answer, so just do that in C.

Comment: @Fredrik I tried declaring int j = i, and then passing in j instead of i, but that didn't work either - is this not the right way to do it (I'm new to C)?

Comment: int *numberToPass = malloc(sizeof int); *numberToPass = i;    Then pass numberToPass to the thread.

Comment: "it does not work" is not a problem description

Comment: @Fredrik Thank you, that worked perfectly

Comment: @Is12Prime, The answer from Tony Delroy in the link you have given should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `c` equivalent to your linked question is slightly more involved.

To prevent a race condition (we're racing against the main thread which is incrementing `i`), we *can't* simply do:

```
pthread_create(&p[i],NULL,somefunc,(void *) &i);
```

So, we need to do what `new` does, but in `c`. So, we use `malloc` (and the thread function should do `free`):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *
somefunc(void *ptr)
{
    int id = *(int*) ptr;

    // main thread _could_ free this after pthread_join, but it would need to
    // remember it -- easier to do it here
    free(ptr);

    // do stuff ...

    return (void *) 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int count = 10;
    pthread_t p[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *ptr = i;
        pthread_create(&p[i],NULL,somefunc,ptr);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        pthread_join(p[i],NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pthread_create(&p[i],NULL,somefunc,(void *) i); - This actually works if typecasted appropriately in the thread_func. This will not have any race condition with main thread as you are only passing a value and not a pointer. Can you explain, why do you think it will not work?

Comment: @Jay It was a typo on my part. I didn't put the `&` in as in the linked page. This was just to recode the solution in `c`